# the_post_thumbnail() without proportion

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

Is it possible to tell Wordpress to show the_post_thumbnail() without the proportion rate.

I need what the width and height to be exactly what I want

```
the_post_thumbnail(array(350,350));
```

If the image is larger than the height, it will only put the height to 350px and ignore the width that i've set to 350 too.

How could I hack this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the timthumb method explained here: 
http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/demo/timthumb-basic/

Works great and will let you do exactly what you need after copying the timthumb.php into the proper WP Theme directory.
Just pass your source image and the h x w of the exact size of your final cropped image, like so:

timthumb.php?src=castle1.jpg&h=350&w=350

Instructions and examples are provided by following the above link.

Good Luck!!

Marcelous

Answer (score 1):

The $size is an optional parameter so there should be nothing wrong with doing
`the_post_thumbnail();`

Comment: Yeah but it calculate the width and height so the image keeps it proportion, I don't want that. I want it the be exactly what I tell it and even it can crop it if it wants.

Comment: I am sorry I misunderstood your question.  Here's what wordpress says to crop your post_thumb_nails() "**PLEASE NOTE: The crop does not work in Wp 3.0+. All that is needed for WP 3.0+ is the call for the thumbnail to post. Then proceed to media in the dashboard and set your thumbnail to crop to the size you wish to use**"